# reCAPTCHA on page template without plugin

Tags: plugins, templates, captcha, plugins-url

I have a template for contact us page which includes a small form with few text fields. I want to add Recaptcha to avoid spams. I already use WP-recaptch plugin which only works for default Registration and comment form. 
If follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php) from recaptcha docs, I get error the same class instance is being declared twice. Thats becoz recaptchalib.php is used by WP-repatcha already. This error will occur even if I use Contact 7 form plugin with recaptcha as every such plugin going to redeclare the same class.

I include  recaptchalib.php from WP_captcha plugin to my template file and it works well to show Recaptcha box, but it doesnt works at validation part - below code doesnt work:

```
    require_once ( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/wp-recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "my key";
    if (empty($_POST['recaptcha_response_field']) || $_POST['recaptcha_response_field'] == '') {
        $captchaErr = 'Please Enter recaptcha text';
    $hasError = true;
   }else{
      $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

      if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly - show error
```

Please can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
if( ! function_exists('plugin_function') )
 require_once('/wp-content/plugins/wp-recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
endif;
```

Not tested but essentially it checks if the plugin exists before trying to add it

Comment: including a URL gives this error "wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0", as it generates http request

Comment: Edited my answer, basically PHP doesn't want you to load files from the same server while using the full URL.

Comment: It's best to use appropriate constant, such as `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`, when forming local paths to files. Including from URLs is bad idea, shouldn't be done.

Comment: WP_PLUGIN_DIR worked well to show the recaptcha box, but it doesnt work at validation part.